# Angular CLI. How can create tmp files for caches

Tags: json, angular, caching, tmp

Angular CLI. How can create tmp files for cache, to don't request every time? For example: if we add new data, then on tmp update json file, then request to tmp files, not backend. Or create files on angular but don't reload page

Comment: Rather than asking a specific question about something that might not be possible, you may be better off working out what you want to achieve and why, and then research that topic.

Comment: In your scenario, how does your website know it isn't using outdated content?